# Displaying different data in the same component based on routes Vue/Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, dynamically-generated

On a button click based on value matching, I am populating an array with objects that i visualise in another component. 
What i'm trying to achieve is this:
Based on the route that i'm currently on i want the same component that visualises the data to display different data.
The data is populated after a series of steps that end with the method that commits the mutation @click below, and in order to reach said steps, you go to different route.
So far, what i'm achieving is generating list on top of the other list when i populate data from more than one route in this component.

```
modifySelectedLimitCardStatus() {
  const payload = [
    this.editedLimitCard.id,
    (this.editedLimitCard.limit_card_selected_status = true)
  ];
  this.$store.commit("selectLimitCard", payload);
}
```

The state & mutation:

```
 selectedLimitCard: [],

 selectLimitCard: (state, payload) => {
    state.limitCards.forEach(limitCard => {
      if (
        limitCard.id === payload[0] &&
        limitCard.limit_card_selected_status !== payload[1]
      ) {
        state.selectedLimitCard.push(limitCard);
        console.log(state.selectedLimitCard);
      }
    });
  }
```

The getter:

```
  getSelectedLimitCard: state => {
    return state.selectedLimitCard;
  }
```

Finally, the component that visualises the data:

```
  <v-list v-for="card in getSelectedLimitCard" :key="card.id"">
        <v-list-tile>
          <v-list-tile-content>№</v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">
            {{ card.limit_card_number }}
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
```

Can someone give me an idea & point me out in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: From one component to another (with vuex as the "mediator" in this case), you can just force the displaying visualization to be bound to the vuex data object holding that array. I'm not sure if that answers your question, but a little clarification would help: are you asking only to have the page driven by the user to drive the visualization in a separate component, where the only change occurs is the vuex data store?

Comment: @HoratiusCocles I think i'm doing that with `v-for="card in getSelectedLimitCard" :key="card.id"`, however every time i populate the component with new data for a different route, it just slaps in on top of it & creates two components, instead of two separate for each route.

Comment: so you're wanting to create multiple views for each route? Like, the first time route_one is triggered, it creates that list, then the first time route_two is triggered, it creates a second list alongside the first visualization? If you "re"trigger an existing route, what is the expected result? Just updating the existing list visualization? Just clarifying questions to make sure I understand before trying to answer you properly.

Comment: @HoratiusCocles What i'm basically trying to achieve is this:
All users start from a default component called `/dashboard`.
They pass thru a stepper, and on the last step they click a button that populates a list at `route1`.
Then, they open another tab (like Google Chrome tabs) that takes them again to `/dashboard` component, but this time, they are at `route2`. They again pass thru the stepper, and at the final step they again click button that populates the same list (same component).
BUT, i want this list to exist with it's data for `route2`, and to have 1 with diff. data for `route1`

Comment: @HoratiusCocles For the question: The data in said list is somewhat static, so no update needed after its selected for the specific route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the feedback from the comment section, it sounds like the storage of data is likely the issue, with the array being an ill-prepared data structure for this task. I would recommend using a simple JSON object, with each key being the route just created:

```
limitCards = {
    routeone: {
        payload: ...,
        other_route_specific_data: ...
    },
    routetwo: {
        payload: ...,
        other_route_specific_data: ...
    }
}
```

You can then bind the data for "v-for" to the return of:

```
limitcards.[current route].selectedLimitCard
```

It seems like this would resolve uniqueness and the ability to show each tab specific data to the route.

Comment: Thank you for for time, and for your extesive answer sir! It's a bit late here right now so i wont be able to implement your solution, but i'm sure it's the correct one, so first thing tomorrow morning!